# Unable to set event in Munit

Tags: anypoint-studio, munit, mulesoft

I had started writing a simple Munit test for one of my flow. In the main flow. I have added a Munit set event to set some URI params to the mainflow.

```
<munit:test name="business-logic-test-suite-mainFlowTest" description="Test">
        <munit:set-event cloneOriginalEvent="false">
        </munit:set-event>
        <set-payload value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="mainFlow" doc:name="Flow-ref to mainFlow"/>
        <munit:assert-payload-equals message="Output message is not matching excepted value #[payload]" expectedValue="#[payload]" doc:name="Assert Payload"/>
    </munit:test>
```

When I try to run the test, the studio is throwing an error "Invalid content was found starting with element 'munit:set-event'". I tried some search on the internet and could not find anything related.

Any clue what could be missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set URI params, you can use `Set Message` component.

Another way to set the URI params is `Message Properties` component.

You can use this [link](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/74393/munits-setting-query-parameters.html) for your reference.